# Where is the best place to farm experience in Final Fantasy XII?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

I have just finished the Pharos tower at Ridorana where you must fight Gabranth, Famfrit and Dr. Cid. My party is currently at an average level of 48. I am trying to figure out where would be the best place to start farming experience.

I have thought of chaining Helvinik in the Necrohol of Nabudis, but when I went to the necrohol, I mostly got between 1k - 1,2k experience per kill.

Surely there must be some faster way or some better place to farm experience. If anyone can point the location out to me, I would gladly appreciate it. Even if it means I must push out tremendous damage to survive (I have the zodiac spear), it would be no problem.

The reason why I ask this question is that , so far, every youtube video I have seen had their characters far beyond level 60. Well, most of them...

Comment: Eek. no comments.... Yet

Comment: I've hadn't had time to play this weekend, so This question is still up for answering <3

Comment: if I remember correctly, there are also ways to auto level when the gambits are set up properly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best place to grind for experience is at Pithead Junction C in the Henne Mines.  Use the switch and kill the Abysteels.  Flip the switch and kill more Abysteels.  Repeat as needed.

You can also chain the Dead Bones (found in Nabreus Deadlands / Overlooking Eternity) for a pretty good amount of experience.

Equipping your characters with Embroidered Tippets will ensure that you make the most use of the experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot! shame you missed my bounty. I usually run in with vaan alone in nabreus deadlands, equipped with grand armor +Helm, zodiak spear and Embroidered Tippet. Decent experience. I'll check for maps online to reach the henne mines area you mentioned. Once again, thanks

Comment: I didn't even see it when there was a bounty!  Oh well, no problem.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found another good place to farm experience. Go to the Ridoranna Cataracts after obtaining the hunt for that weird shape shifting dude. Once you get past the three floors, each floor will have enemies that constantly re-spawn and I know the second and third drop about 5k exp which with Embroided Tippet is 10k per kill. I'm not sure about the first floor though.